# Translator with BST in C

Tags: c, binary-search-tree

So I'm making a program that can take a word from keyboard and output the Spanish translation of it using a file with all the translations. Right now I'm using a BST as my function. In my code I use strtok() to break up the string that is being inputted from a file. However, every word has four random characters in front of them. Here is what I have...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SIZE 8001

// BST code
struct BSTnode{
    char engWord[128], spanWord[1000];
    struct BSTnode *left, *right;
};

struct BSTnode *root = NULL;

struct BSTnode *newBSTNode(char *engWord, char *spanWord){
    struct BSTnode *newNode;
    newNode = (struct BSTnode*)malloc(sizeof(struct BSTnode));
    strcpy(newNode->engWord, engWord);
    strcpy(newNode->spanWord, spanWord);
    newNode->left = newNode->right = NULL;
    return newNode;
}

void insert(char *engWord, char *spanWord){
    struct BSTnode *parent, *current, *newnode = NULL;
    int res = 0;
    if(root == NULL){
        root = newBSTNode(engWord, spanWord);
        return;
    }
    for(current = root; current != NULL; 
    current = (res > 0)?current-   >right:current->left){
        res = strcasecmp(engWord, current->engWord);
        parent = current;
    }
    newnode = newBSTNode(engWord, spanWord);
    res > 0?(parent->right = newnode):(parent->left = newnode);
    return;
}

void findEngWord(char *str){
    struct BSTnode *temp = NULL;
    int flag = 0, res = 0;
    if(root == NULL){
        printf("FAIL!!!!!!");
        return;
    }
    temp = root;
    int counter = 1;
    while(temp){
        if((res = strcasecmp(temp->engWord, str)) == 0){
            printf("\t%s\n\t%d BST nodes", temp->spanWord, counter);
            flag = 1;
            break;
        }
        temp = (res > 0)?temp->left:temp->right;
        counter++;
    }
    if(!flag)
        printf("\t---NOT found (in BST)\n\t%d BST nodes", counter);
    return;

}

void openFileBST(){
    // open file
    FILE* filePnt = fopen("Spanish.txt", "r");
    char input[500], *first, *second;

    // If file is invalid
    if(filePnt == NULL){
        printf("Could not open file. Termination Program...");
        exit(0);
    }

    while(fgets(input, 500, filePnt) != NULL){
        first = strtok(filePnt, "\t");
        second = strtok(NULL, "\n");
        // Test prints
        printf("%s\n", &first);
        printf("%s\n", &second);

        insert(&first, &second);
    }
    fclose(filePnt);
}

void search(){
    char *tempStr, exitStr = "-1";

    // Ask user to input word
    printf("Enter a word you want to have translated. (type -1 to exit)
        \n-------------------------\n");
    while(1){
        printf("\n- ");
        fgets(tempStr, 99, stdin);

        // Failed exit statement
        //if(strcmp(tempStr, exitStr) == 0){
        //    printf("test");
        //    break;
        //}


        findEngWord(&tempStr);
    }
}

int main()
{
    openFileBST();
    search();
}
```

Here is a picture of my output[image]

Because of the first four characters I'm pretty sure I can't correctly search for a English word. Is it something with my strtok function, or my code? Thank you guys for the help in advance!

Comment: Please see [How to complete a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](/help/mcve).

Comment: In the `search` function, you have `char *tempStr` and `fgets(tempStr, 99, stdin);` That won't work correctly because `tempStr` is not initialized before it's used, so it doesn't point to valid memory. To fix it, change the declaration to `char tempStr[100]`. Also, the call to `findEngWord` should be `findEngWord(tempStr)` without the ampersand.

Comment: _Because of the first four characters I'm pretty sure I can't correctly..._ A broken output does not mean that searching does not work. You should not assume things if you can easily test it. And please, do not post screenshots of your output. Just copy the text is much more convenient for any reader.

Comment: I'm sorry about that, I couldn't figure out how to copy the text out of my command prompt. I tried the swap from the pointer of tempStr and it would go through the test print statements, but crash at the search prompt. Thank you for the answer!

Comment: What does your text file look like?

Comment: @RoadRunner It contains a bunch of translations. The first couple of like look like this...  
aardvark cerdo hormiguero
aardvark oso hormiguero[Noun]
aardvarks cerdos hormigueros
aardvarks osos hormigueros 
ab prefijo que indica separacio/n

Answer (score 3):

In the `openFileBST` function the variables `first` and `second` are of type `char *`. Now if you get a pointer to those variables, with e.g. `&first`, you get something which is of type `char **`. Not the same as what your other functions (or `printf` with the `"%s"` format) are expecting.

Remove the address-of operator `&` when passing the variables to the functions.

Comment: I tried doing that and the program crashed. It would even make it to my test print function.

Comment: @DylanForsyth Probably because you do the same in the `search` function when you call `findEngWord`. Also in the `search` function, the variable `exitStr` is *not* a pointer variable, it's a single `char`. And of course `tempStr` is not an array but an uninitialized pointer. All of this should have been found by the compiler. It did shout warnings at you? Did you read them?

Comment: Ah I see what you mean. I removed all the address operators from my function calls, but when I call my `insert` function in `openFileBST` it will crash. I'm not sure it's any of my other function because it will not even make the `insert` function call before it throws a fit. Thank you again for the quick answers by the way!

Comment: @DylanForsyth If you get crashes you should really use a debugger to find out *where* the crashes are. When the debugger has caught the crash, and you are in your code, then you can examine variables and their values to see if they look okay.